# Ionic2 view elements hide by controller property

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic2 app, based on ionic sidemenu template. I'd like to show/hide menu items based on a boolean property (user logged in). My problem is that the items in the menu don't refresh at all, change takes effect only when I restart the application.

Part of my app.html that contains the menu:

```
<ion-list>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let p of pages">
    <button menuClose ion-item (click)="openPage(p)" *ngIf="!p.hidden">
      {{p.title}}
    </button>
  </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

pages is an array as it was originally in the template, I just added a hidden property:

```
this.pages = [
      { title: '1', component: Page1, hidden: false },
      { title: '2', component: Page2, hidden: !this.registered },
      { title: '3', component: Page3, hidden: !this.registered },
      { title: '4', component: Page4, hidden: false },
      { title: '5', component: Page5, hidden: false },
      { title: '6', component: Page6, hidden: this.registered }
    ];
```

I have a registration screen on Page6, so that shows when the user is not registered. I have 2 more pages (2,3) which must only be shown when the user has an active session (registered). These reflects on the hidden property.

After login or registration I publish a `user.registered` event which I catch in this controller and set the registered property accordingly. What am I missing here? How can I show or hide these menuitems?

Comment: Do you creating this.pages array again or just changing the value of this.registered?

Comment: @aminarghavani Just changing this.registered. It should work, right?

Comment: I think your array do not update.

Comment: @aminarghavani Yeah, you were right. I have updated the whole array on the event and everything shows up and hides as needed. Thanks. Will you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The this.pages array do not updating.
You need to update this.pages array.